# Is there a way to store sum using calculated fields in RSA Archer GRC?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

There are two fields. The first contains numeric value. The second should contain the sum of the all changes of the first field.
Can I use calculated field for this task? If so what would be inside the formula?

For example:

**Update 1**
First field changed manually to 100.
Second automatically contains 100.

**Update 2**
First field changed manually to 200.
Second automatically contains 300.

**Update 3**
First field changed manually to 100.
Second automatically contains 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculations can reference themselves.

So, for example, let's say you have a numeric field named Total Sum.  For that field, you would use the following calculation
`SUM([Field with value],[Total Sum])`

Answer (score 0):

While using the calculations suggested by DjP above, you also need to control the Total Sum field's calculation sequence, otherwise it will keep on increasing.